# Integral of Velocity

Tags: calculus, integration

The integral of velocity plots position and not change in position. But the definition of the integral is the area under the velocity curve and the area under the velocity curve is change in position. So why doesn't the integral of velocity plot change in position?

Comment: first of all, the definition of an integral is not the area under the curve of a velocity curve, that is an application of integration.

Comment: Maybe help you see [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rfG8ce4nNh0&list=PLZHQObOWTQDMsr9K-rj53DwVRMYO3t5Yr&index=8).

Comment: @DonlansDonlans sorry for my poor choice of wording that's not what I meant

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The information presented in the question seems a bit misguided. The plot of the integral of velocity, that is $\displaystyle f_1(t) = \int_{a}^{t}v(x)\,dx$ does show the change in position. In this case, we will have $f(a)=0$. In fact, if we change $f$ so that $\displaystyle f_2(t)=\int_a^tv(x)\,dx+p(a)$, then $f(t)=p(t)$. So while $f_1(t)$ may not show the position itself, it DOES show the change in position from some reference point.

Answer (score 0):

The definite integral of the velocity from time $a$ to time $b$ is the change in position over that time interval.

You can only specify the position of an object relative to some point. "The position" makes sense only in a coordinate system. That might be latitude and longitude or the position on a line with some fixed $0$ position and scale specified.